# Read text from PDF on .NET Core using Any open source / non-licensed packages

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-core

I need to read *PDF* and convert it in a *.Txt*. I tried `iTextSharp` as free library, it was working fine but not compatible with .NET Core.

*Code snippet in iTextSharp*

```
string prevPage = "";
for (int page = 5; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
{
  ITextExtractionStrategy its = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
  var s = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, its);
  if (prevPage != s) sb.Append(s);
  prevPage = s;
}
reader.Close();
```

Also, I tried `iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core` but it does not work as well as the other one, and the results are not accurate.

One of the downsides `iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core` is that it does not support encoding and results in *noise* in the extracted text of the PDF

My stringbuilder looks like the image below:

[image]

Comment: i have used ghostscruot before with .net. there is a net core version maybe you can try it https://www.nuget.org/packages/GhostScript.NetCore/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I ask you an help to use it?

Comment: **Off-topic because...** It's seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.

Comment: *So is there is a good library in C# .net Core free to read a pdf and convert it into a txt file?* → When the library will be considered as a good library? & How do you expect to convert images or tables or links to text format. These are some parameters which makes the question off-topic. You may want to edit the question and asking a specific question. To do so, take a look at [ASK] .

Comment: You were right, I added some details. Especially, I just need to parse the text from a PDF file, don't need images or tables formatted in some way, just the text.

Comment: using ghostscript you can do something along the lines of https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET/blob/master/Ghostscript.NET.Samples/Samples/RasterizerSample1.cs however in order to perform ocr and extract text you need something like tesseract-ocr https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/

Comment: @RobNone, did you get a chance to try it out the post below ?, I was able to extract PDF to text with it.

Comment: Clint, this afternoon I will try it and give you a feedback. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**[Approach: PDFPig (Apache:2.0 License)](https://licenses.nuget.org/Apache-2.0)**

Install Nuget Package *PdfPig*

Tested on .Net Core 3.1

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(pdfPath1))
using (UglyToad.PdfPig.PdfDocument document = UglyToad.PdfPig.PdfDocument.Open(stream))
{
    var page = document.GetPage(2);
    return string.Join(" ", page.GetWords());
}
```

---

**[Approach: iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core(GNU General Public License)](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.0-standalone.html)**

Install Nuget *iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core*

> It is an unofficial port of the last LGPL version of the iTextSharp (V4.1.6) to .NET Core.

*Tested on .Net Core 3.1*

```
var reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath1);
var streamBytes = reader.GetPageContent(1);
var tokenizer = new PrTokeniser(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(streamBytes));
var sb = new StringBuilder();
while (tokenizer.NextToken())
{
    if (tokenizer.TokenType == PrTokeniser.TK_STRING)
    {
         var currentText = tokenizer.StringValue;
         currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
         sb.Append(tokenizer.StringValue);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Extracted text "+sb);
```

---

**[Approach: GrapeCity.Documents.PDF(Licensed)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GrapeCity.Documents.Pdf/3.0.0.420/License)**

Install `Nuget-Package *GrapeCity.Documents.Pdf`
Is crossplatform library allows for creation, modification and analysis of PDF docs

*Tested on .Net Core 3.1*

```
    var doc = new GcPdfDocument();
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(pdfPath1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    doc.Load(fs);
    //To extract Page 1
    var tmap_page2 = doc.Pages[0].GetTextMap();
    tmap_page2.GetFragment(out TextMapFragment newFragment, out string Extractedtext);

    Console.WriteLine("Extracted Text: \n\n" +Extractedtext);
```

Comment: I think this library is not LGPL, I'm right?

Comment: Edit: LGPL or OpenSource.

Comment: @RobNone, I don't think it is [neither](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GrapeCity.Documents.Pdf/3.0.0.420/License)

Comment: @RobNone, there you go edited the post ;)

Comment: I tried to use this code, it read my PDF but sb returns like the image I added in my post unfortunately...

Comment: The solution provided by Clint with PDFPig works FINE! It's only net.core 3.1, open-source and nice working.

Comment: I have tested the 3 libraries with the following results in an azure funtion net core 3.1.
iTextSharep.LGPLv2.Core-> the reading of spatial characters towards the logic that had in a text to spetch. fail to

PdfPig was not able to read the document. fails the first test

GrapeCity.Documents.Pdf I work correctly with a fairly simple code.